# Sending envelope to recipients in parallel (REST/C# SDK)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We're currently sending via the REST API using the [C# sdk](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client). I would like to send an envelope to multiple recipients in parallel rather than in sequential order. I would prefer not to use bulk recipients. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: By reading the documentation of the tool?

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't see in the REST API docs, as described below, that if you left it off they would be sent simultaneously. It isn't mentioned on that parameter in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the **RoutingOrder** if you want to send the signing request to multiple recipients simultaneously.

> If your document has more than one recipient, you can choose to set a **routing order**(aka signing order). The routing order lets you control the order in which your recipients receive and sign your document.

Here is an example using the [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

```
var recipients = new Recipients()
{
    Signers = new List<Signer>()
    {
         new Signer()
         {
              Email = "recipientone@acme.com",
              Name = "recipient one",
              RecipientId = "1",
              //RoutingOrder = "1",
              Tabs = new Tabs()
              {
                  SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>()
                  {
                      new SignHere()
                      {
                        DocumentId = "1", XPosition = "100", YPosition = "300", PageNumber = "1"
                      }
                  }
              }
         },
          new Signer()
         {
              Email = "recipienttwo@acme.com",
              Name = "recipient two",
              RecipientId = "2",
              //RoutingOrder = "2",
              Tabs = new Tabs()
              {
                  SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>()
                  {
                      new SignHere()
                      {
                        DocumentId = "1", XPosition = "100", YPosition = "500", PageNumber = "1",
                      }
                  }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks CodingDawg. I didn't see that documented, only that setting it specified the order. If multiple recipients I had assumed, incorrectly, that you had to set the routing order.

Can you tell me, if there are x signers sent simultaneously, does that count as x envelopes or still as a single envelope? Our API integration services multiple clients each with their own DocuSign account so that question will almost certainly come up.

Comment: It will still count as a single envelope.